# Would someone please explain why these question closures are such a bad thing?

Tags: discussion

I spent much of the past week involved in a rather extended discussion about closed questions. Near as I can tell, here is the logic:

- ELU has a lot of closed questions, at least compared to other StackExchange sites.
- Instead of closing questions, we ought to fix them and answer them. After all, doesn't this community exist to help people?
- When a question gets closed, no one else can provide an answer; therefore, closures are a bad thing. Also, closures might make newer users feel unwelcome.
- Since questions **are** getting closed instead of being left open, these closures indicate that ELU is a *down-arrow clicking clique*, a bunch of *anal-retentive geeks who need to get a life*, *people who are busy protecting their own little fiefdom from alleged pollution*, *run like a monopolistic cartel by a bunch of pseudo-intellectual pretentious linguistic professor wannabees*.  Moreover, ELU is, *without a doubt, too snobby, and the rudest community on StackExchange*. (The text in italics is not mere colorful language of mine; these were taken as excerpts from the [discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/waning-gap-of-acceptable-questions) – some of which were upvoted).

**So, I examined the last 20 closed questions on ELU.**  Here's what I found:

---

**[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94384/why-an-is-used-in-december-1972-u-s-astronaut-eugene-cern-an-becomes-the-las)) Why “an” is used in “December 1972 U.S. astronaut Eugene CERN an becomes the last person to set foot on the moon”?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in two comments): because it's supposed to say "Cernan", not "CERN an".

**[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94371/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-regex)) What is the correct pronunciation of “Regex”?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in two answers and several comments): It's pronounced with a hard *g*. Moreover, a link was provided where this specific example was discussed in a more generic but [related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56164/pronunciation-of-letters-g-and-c-in-blend-words) question.

**[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94366/usage-differences-between-smile-vs-laugh-vs-sneer-vs-chuckle-vs-giggle-vs-titter)) Usage differences between Smile vs laugh vs Sneer vs chuckle vs giggle vs titter vs grin vs beam vs smirk vs simper vs snicker vs Singger?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in three comments): Some of these are ways to laugh, and some are ways to smile, but this question as a whole is probably asking too much as a single question.

**[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94356/why-do-you-write-receive-with-ei-but-retrieve-with-ie)) Why do you write “receive” with “ei” but “retrieve” with “ie”?** [closed as duplicate]

> - **answer** (explained at duplicate question): Basically, English vocabulary is a mix of mostly proto-Germanic and proto-French, the languages in use by the Saxons and Normans respectively during the Norman invasion and occupation of the British isles. (NOTE: there is much more to this [very detailed answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34356/why-is-it-true-that-i-before-e-except-after-c) than I have copied here.)

**[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94354/does-doctor-means-phd-or-physician)) Does Doctor means PhD. or Physician?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in comments): The word can be used as a title in either case.

**[6](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94339/does-shakespeare-use-the-word-whence-incorrectly)) Do Shakespeare use the word “whence” incorrectly?** [closed]

> - **answer** (given in one answer): It's a flexible word, and it's a bit harsh to suggest that Shakespeare has made a mistake.

**[7](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94323/a-girl-whom-i-have-a-crush-on)) A girl *who* (or *whom*) I have a crush on… (?)** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in two answers): "whom" is formally correct, although "who" is often used in conversational English; for more information, see this [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/whats-the-rule-for-using-who-or-whom).

**[8](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94317/which-one-is-correct-non-or-non)) Which one is correct, *non* or *non-*?** [closed as duplicate]

> - **answer** (not given at the question, but easily found at duplicate): There are three types of compound words in English: closed, hyphenated, and open. There are also four useful articles cited at the [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889).

**[9](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94316/subject-verb-and-object-agreement)) Which one is the correct form: “The only thing which doesn't work *is* the engines,” or “The only thing which doesn't work *are* the engines.”** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in several comments): The short answer is "are"; there are other considerations explained in the comments.

**[10](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94307/verb-or-phrase-meaning-to-serve-as-evidence-of-ones-character)) what is the meaning of expressyou: Want to know whether it is "Convey you". or is there any other word that can give the message reflect your character.** [closed]

> - **answer**: This question was not answered in its original form, but one user has tried to reword the question, and subsequently provided an answer to that interpretation. Since that time, it has received three reopen votes.

**[11](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94304/should-punctuation-characters-have-a-preceding-space)) Should punctuation characters have a preceding space?** [closed]

> - **answer** (provided in a comment): Short answer: no. Long answer: for more information, see this [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark).

**[12](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94303/spelling-or-grammar-error)) Would the wrong form of *your* or *you're* be considered a spelling or grammar error?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in an answer): That would depend on the intent of the writer.

**[13](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94297/meaning-of-the-word-nonlesson)) What is the meaning of the word “nonlesson”** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in a comment): It's a simple negation. In the context of "lessons learned" it would mean either (1) a lesson that was not learned (i.e, a repeated mistake) or (2) something that was thought to be a lesson, but was not (i.e, an erroneous conclusion).

**[14](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94283/i-got-it-covered-vs-ive-got-it-covered)) “I got it covered” vs “I've got it covered”: Which is correct and why?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in two answers): It can mean different things in different contexts; sometimes one is slang for the other.

**[15](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94278/what-did-in-this-sentences-refers-to)) What does the “did” in this sentences refers to?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in a comment): It refers to the word *differ* in the previous sentence.

**[16](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94266/usage-difference-between-modest-vs-decent)) Usage difference between modest vs decent?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in one answer): Modest and decent have overlapping semantic ranges. They can mean the same thing, but do not always. (NOTE: The answer includes much more elaboration not provided here).

**[17](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94255/the-plural-of-conch)) What is the plural of “conch”?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in three different answers): When "conch" is pronounced to rhyme with "honk", the plural is "conchs"; when pronounced as a near-rhyme with "launch", the plural is "conches".

**[18](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94251/hail-mary-glory-be-in-the-plural)) In the Catholic rosary, there is a short prayer called "Glory Be." Would the plural be *Glory Bes* or *Glory Be's*? Likewise, do you say *10 Hail Marys*?** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in an answer provided): Use an apostrophe. Moreover, more information is provided via a link to a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop).

**[19](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94247/where-to-place-the-word-easily)) Where to place the word “easily”? Is it: *Do you want to edit and share your bookmarks easily?* Or: *Do you want to easily edit and share your bookmarks?*** [closed]

> - **answer** (explained in two answers): Best to put it at the end.

**[20](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94231)) What is the question to be asked to get an answer "The *44th* president of United States of America is Barack Obama."** [closed]

> - **answer**: Not provided, but the links to 17 duplicate questions *were* provided.

---

If we want to talk about quality as a whole, these questions don't strike me as particularly well-researched, or intriguing to a serious language enthusiast. They seem more basic than profound. (If that observation paints me as a snob, I apologize. I call 'em as I see 'em.)

Still, if the issue is really about helping people, just about all 20 O.P.'s got an answer to their question, despite the fact that these questions may have been ultimately closed.

**So, what is my question?**

To those who have been bemoaning the fact that a high closure rate allegedly portrays us an uncaring, insular community – and to those who see us openly characterized as *“geeks who need to get a life,”* and respond with a hearty *“Hear, hear!”* – I ask:

- Which of these questions should have remained open?  Why?
- Even if a few of these questions should have remained open, do you really believe an overwhelming *majority* of these questions should have remained open? In other words, do these closures really portray a reckless and egregious misuse of privilege by so-called power-users? Please explain.
- Do you find any difference between a community that closes questions while still providing answers (perhaps through links or comments), and a community that would close questions *without* providing answers?  In other words, does the closure itself outweigh any helpful information that was provided by members of the community?

I ask because this week wasn't the first time I've seen this line of reasoning: *a lot of questions get closed, therefore you're all just a bunch of snobs*. However, when I search for evidence of that snobbery, I keep finding a slew of rather mediocre questions – usually with helpful answers, by the way – rather than hard evidence of an unhelpful clique. But maybe I'm just missing something, in which case maybe you can help me out.

Comment: "So, I examined the last 20 closed questions on ELU" - by what criteria? By the date of closure? Or date of last activity? If you don't disclose your criteria, it's possible you may be [cherry-picking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking_(fallacy)) closed questions to suit your conclusion.

Comment: The "regex" question was an ***exact*** duplicate, not as a related question (I was about to argue that it shouldn't have been closed when I looked at the duplicate question, and realized it was also asking about the word "regex"). However, it seems to me that the answers should be merged, because the regex question got some good answers that don't match the answer on the duplicate question.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I picked the 20 most recently-closed questions, from the list of questions sorted by the order they were asked, (i.e., from [this list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions), sorted by _Newest_). There was no cherry-picking; I figured 20 was a decent enough sample size. (Truth be told, I picked the number 20 before I had looked at *any* of the questions, so I had no idea what I'd find). If you think that sample size is too small, you're welcome to continue down the list and analyze the next 20. ;^)

Comment: @PeterShor: I didn't regard them as exact duplicates, because one asked about the general case, and the other asked about the specific case. In other words, I thought there was a slight difference between, "How do you pronounce _regex_?" and, "How do you pronounce a blend word with a _g_, e.g. _regex_?"  All that said, I'd support your merge proposal.

Comment: Why should easy straightforward questions (which you describe as mediocre) be such an issue for you? You define yourself as a snob by merely stating this. If these questions are of no challenge to you, why do you downvote and close them? Yes those kind of questions may not challenge you or your cliquey snobby mates so ignore them. Is this SE about English language usage or is it just about really hard, tricky, difficult obscure questions that challenge the snobs like you who populate the site? It looks like I was right for once, it was au revoir and not adieu.

Comment: @J.R., you need to exclude closed-as-dupe questions from your analysis, because (AFAIK) nobody is arguing against them. Also, your analysis would be more useful if you listed the close reason each time.

Comment: @Marthaª: I suppose I could have excluded duplicate questions from my analysis, but much of the previous conversation I alluded to uses this logic: _ELU closes a lot of questions; therefore, it is populated by presumptuous snobs_. (It's actually worded like this: "I revisited EL&U to find about a third of questions on the main page marked [closed]." and, "I noticed that the proportion of questions closed here is much greater than on Math or any of several SE computer forums I read.") If a significant portion of those questions are duplicates, that might also refute that initial premise.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Bonjour! Um, who said these are "an issue" for me? This was meant to be an objective analysis on the first 20 questions I could find – I'm not incriminating them by discussing them here. BTW, on #3, I left a comment, and didn't vote to close. On #12 I left a comment on an answer, and upvoted that answer. On #10, I upvoted the answer. #6 I improved with an edit. I left two comments on #16. Out of the 20 questions I listed, I only voted to close on #14 and #16. I downvoted only one of the 20, and there were at least 6 that I hadn't even opened until I began this experiment.

Comment: My point still remains. Is the site about English Language and Usage in all forms or is it simply about the really tricky, hard potentially *challenging* questions that more academic users will enjoy answering because they feel they may learn something themselves? If so why are the simpler questions (still within the FAQ) being closed and/or down voted? Because the more snobby among us feel they're beneath them to answer? That's my point.

Comment: J.R. I agree with you, but these words are obscure for most high-rep users, and they both signal and confirm a sense of exclusion of the members that do not belong to the Reg's "staff", not for the relevance of their meanings (they probably have their correspondence in high-rep's brain circuits), but at a symbolic level. The use of such phrases, in this and other questions recently asked, invite a perception of cultural difference and a salutary resistance to the appropriation of the main site by those users. Normal users are not part of the snob community represented in your ...

Comment: ... question, and language is used by Reg's "staff" as the deliberate instrument of this exclusion.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Look through the [700+](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/18220/j-r?tab=answers) questions I've answered; you'll find most of them are rather basic. You've called me a snob, you've inferred I can't read very well, all because you see a lot of closed questions. I analyzed the closed questions, and I found a lot of duplicates, and a lot of patient answers given, yet we are _still_ characterized as too high-minded to help those that write those questions, no matter how bad they might be. Yes, you've made your point, and every ELU downvote probably cements it in your own mind.

Comment: To answer your question, I think the site _is_ about all forms of English, but some basic rules apply (like on **every other Stack Exchange forum**): stay on topic, abide by the FAQ, and realize this is a meritocracy where you build trust and reputation by the quality of your contributions. I don't downvote people who struggle with their English or ask basic questions, but I have downvoted when people act like the users here are nothing more than a convenient concierge, and work from the mindset "Why should I open a dictionary, when it's so much easier to ask here?"

Comment: "these questions don't strike me as ... intriguing to a serious language enthusiast." Please don't confuse "enthusiast" with "expert". How "profound" you find these questions is meaningless. They pretty much all fall happily under the guidelines set out in the FAQ, and closing them removes the possibility for further constructive or interesting discussion (even if not interesting to you). If you want to close, it's up to you to explain why nipping a discussion in the bud is necessary. Were these questions, you know, wasting internet? Or people's time? Or was this just overboard housekeeping?

Comment: @J.R. I appreciate to an extent I'm chastising the messenger rather than the originators and I appreciate at least in part your patience in answering my comments. I just feel it's a shame that this particular SE has taken a rather high brow attitude which is not prevalent (in my experience so far) of the others I'm a member of. You mention meritocracy, and therein lies its problem - it contains far too many academics who have lost touch with a living language they so profess to admire. So many questions are answered with such language the OP probably doesn't understand.

Comment: @Billy: It seems like no matter how I word it, I piss someone off, or "prove their point." Enthusiast, expert, profound – I don't mean to imply every question needs to be a serious nut to crack, but when questions ask about typographical errors, or something that's already been answered, or something that's obtusely vague, or something that's easily found in a dictionary, I don't understand the hullabaloo when these questions are closed. Perhaps more importantly, I don't like it when people observe that, and then jump to the conclusion that we're nothing but a bunch high-browed housekeepers.

Comment: @Billy: RE: _"If you want to close, it's up to you to explain why nipping a discussion in the bud is necessary."_ As I mentioned earlier, out of the 20 questions I analyzed here, I only voted to close two of them, and, on one of those two, I left a comment clearly stating my qualms with the question. It's not that I felt a need to "nip the discussion in the bud," but it was because I felt the question needed more elaboration and basic research. BTW, I've dispensed such advice before on several occasions, and often upvoted and/or answered those same questions after such edits were made.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I think I tried to explain this before – the other sites you visit do the same thing. Questions that are off-topic or poorly researched get closed and downvoted. It happens on Math, like in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146032). It happens on cooking, like in [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29161). Yes, it happens more often on ELU, but I honestly beleive that's more due to question quality than member snobbery, which is why I did this analysis, which showed at least 19 of 20 people got their questions answered by ELU members.

Comment: @J.R. Then, with respect, you should stop rewording your claim, and accept that we understand and disagree. Questions that are answerable, don't break rules, etc. should by default be left open, even if they are stupid or poorly researched. "You must be at least this clever to ride" should not be the SE culture - some new users, *particularly* the ones with stupid questions, might not know how to research their own question, or what counts as a valid question. *Particularly* in those cases, we need to promote healthy discussion, not tell them to shut up until they've gone away and learnt more.

Comment: @Billy: That aligns with jlovegren's position below. As I stated there, I consider that a legitimate position up for discussion; maybe the community could do some soul-searching in that regard. For the record, though, I don't remember finding any instance in any of those 20 questions where a new user was told to "shut up," or told to "go away." That's apparently _your_ interpretation of a close vote, but there may be others – particularly those who are leaving helpful comments along with their votes – who would disagree with that interpretation.

Comment: @J.R. When you close a question, nobody can post new answers, only those with a high enough reputation can leave comments, and new questions on the same topic opened later in the hope of sparking discussion will be marked as 'duplicates', redirected to the old thread and closed again. It sets a precedent: "this question does not live up to our standards, and you will not talk about it here". If that's not telling someone to shut up, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Billy: can you not see the difference between 'Don't ask this question again' (or, *possibly*, questions like this one), and 'Shut up and go away'?

Comment: @TimLymington Both leave the user in question feeling affronted and rejected by the community, all future interested readers of that question feeling unwelcome, and (if such responses are common enough) all new visitors to the site feeling as though they're treading on eggshells. The former technically leaves open the possibility to come back and ask another question later, but what masochist is going to want to? The former's not even any politer than the latter - it says the same thing in a less childish way. What's the difference?

Comment: @Billy: RE: _"only those with a high enough reputation can leave comments."_ Leaving comments is a privilege awarded at **50** points, so only the greenest users would be excluded; very few would be left out of the discussion. RE: _"new questions on the same topic opened later in the hope of sparking discussion will be marked as 'duplicates', redirected to the old thread and closed again."_ It would be hard to find an example of this, I think. Duplicates get directed to questions that have been _answered_; not to questions that were _closed_ and not answered.

Comment: RE: _"this question does not live up to our standards, and you will not talk about it here"_ I've never heard that said. I've heard "This question is off-topic, so it will be closed," and I've heard, "This question needs to be improved, or it will be closed." When questions don't meet "standards," users are exhorted to _improve_ them, not shut up.

Comment: @J.R. I'm having trouble working out how to answer you here. (1) It is predominantly the greenest users I'm talking about - the ones who are still testing the waters and don't know whether to join this community or not. Not coincidentally, they are the people whose questions are most likely to be closed. (2) Again, what you think is an "answer" may not be an answer to what the OP wanted to know, or what someone who turns up a year later through Google with a similar question wants to know.

Comment: (3) I've heard only "this question is now closed", not "please improve your question so that it doesn't get closed". I link you to a thread that I linked Reg Dwight to a few minutes ago: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/ Yes, it's a duplicate question. But so what? That (brand new) user got treated like crap, and probably won't come back. Nobody exhorted him to improve his post - it just got closed abruptly. For people like Reg and Fumble - 40k and 50k rep respectively - this is normal, boring and second nature. To a new user, it's a big neon sign saying "you are not welcome".

Comment: @Billy, (1) The question is still open [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16306); why don't you leave an answer, along w/ an additional comment at the newly closed question, directing the new user to take a look. You could set a precident for making new users feel more welcome. (2) The user wasn't exhorted to improve the post, because it wasn't closed for being poorly researched, just a dupl. (3) Two users left answers – that's hardly "you're not welcome here." (4) Reg & FF close dups most often not because they're rude, but because they've been here longer, and recognize them.

Comment: @J.R. (1) Please don't imply that disagreeing with the system makes it my personal responsibility to patch it up. I have nowhere near the time necessary to undo the damage being done. More to the point, I have no desire to stick around here long if I'm the only one who thinks this is an important issue. I am testing the waters, for the final time, for signs of cooperation.

Comment: (2), (3), (4) You're talking past me. I am trying to make clear that old-timers are probably scaring away newbies by doing things that *they* don't consider rude, but which are bad etiquette anywhere except SE. You're telling me things we both know, and missing my point: people outside of SE and recently joined users *won't* know these things, and *will* find the gratuitous closure of posts rude, and *will* feel unwelcome. The etiquette here is abnormal, and we need to recognise that so as not to become insular.

Comment: @Billy: If you're not part of the solution, you're part of the problem. :^)

Comment: I came back to the site after a long time and I honestly will never ask a question here again. Half of the most recently asked questions have overall negative points without a single comment stating why the question is bad. The answer I got does not in my opinion qualify as an answer and overall my experience here was awful. I second @Billy in his comments: I felt very unwelcome and unworthy of the site. Someone even pointed me to a proposal for an SE site for people learning English, which at best is patronising, at worst offensive.

Comment: And I think this shows the problem: "Of the votes cast, 289 were up-votes and 216 were down-votes."

Comment: @Vivi: I'm sorry to see you go, if you really go. You've asked some really good questions and made some excellent comments. You'd be missed – and I mean that sincerely.

Comment: "it contains far too many academics who have lost touch with a living language they so profess to admire." — My experience on sister sites is that academics post (and vote) under their real names. My guess is that we have a lot of grad students and abandoned Ph.D.s who feel better about their superior knowledge of English after slagging (and closing) foreigners' silly, or not so silly, questions. You would think they were charged by the byte for each question left open.

Comment: @Billy "but which are bad etiquette anywhere except SE"; except I think the point is they are bad etiquette on SE except on ELU. The explicandum of this discussion is the much higher closure rate on ELU relative all or almost all sister forums.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Ah, yes. That is what I intended to say. (Such closures do occur on other SEs, but (at least in my experience) they seem to be far fewer in number and the unfair ones are more readily contested.) Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I’m calling your bluff: please **back up your *allegation*** of “much higher closer rate on ELU relative [to] all or almost all sister forums” with cold, hard data. (BTW, these are not “forums”.) Every time I run the numbers, I arrive at the opposite conclusion, so do us all the courtesy of showing us *your* numbers. Even if it were true — and I am convinced it is not — in cannot be questioned that ELU is in a unique position, where everybody and his dog shows up wanting us to proofread their PostIt notes. “Never have so many come with so little.”

Comment: @tchrist: Any way to access stats questions that are deleted? The stats of "closed" don't seem nearly as scary in the search once closed then deleted disappear. I'd gladly make the statistics but I don't think I'd get far with moderators' diligence in removing closed questions.

Comment: @SF.: It seems like most closed ELU questions _don't_ disappear. Ironically, that's often what sparks these accusations of snobbery and elitism – a high number of closed questions on the front page. The mods might eliminate that by deleting more questions, but they don't. It would be ironic if other SEs deleted their closed questions sooner, making them appear more "friendly," but I don't spend enough time on other SE boards to even speculate if that might be true. One other note: if you did manage to access that data, you should exclude deleted questions by Nortonn S – those shouldn't count.

Comment: @SF. No, you don’t have enough reputation to look at deleted questions. And only moderators can get much in the way of statistics regarding them; high-rep users can see them, and can also see a list of the last 50 that were deleted in a given time period. Deletions of non-spam postings are rare; deletions of spam are common, and should not count anyway.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but this comment thread has long grown past the point of being useful. At this point any additional comment is unlikely to so much as get noticed by anyone other than the person writing it and the person being at-mentioned. If there is still anything to be said that is a) on-topic and b) hasn't been rehashed ten times over by now, I urge everyone to continue the discussion in chat. A dedicated chat room can be created if you wish. This thread, meanwhile, might have to get trimmed or locked. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd prefer it *not* to be in chat, precisely so that I *can* keep reading. In either case, though, I'd prefer it to be shorter and less scatty - perhaps it can be condensed into separate, more specific questions (if these are indeed separate issues)?

Comment: @Vivi I am sad to hear that and I ask you to reconsider. If you find a comment offensive, flag it and it will be dealt with. (In fact, I am not seeing it so it must have been dealt with already.) The  rest of the comments seem rather civil, so do the answers. If you are not satisfied with the answer you get, please do not accept it, so people try harder. At any rate, leaving the site over one question, especially without bringing it to mod attention, is not helping anyone. And leaving the site *after* bringing it to mod attention is overkill. Stick around and help change things for the better.

Comment: @RegDwighт I tried to find the chat you mentioned but didn't see you. I am willing to discuss this issue with you. Regarding the comment, it was deleted by the person who wrote it together with his answer and the many comments which had been written below it, some of which not very nice.

Comment: @RegDwighт The problem wasn't just the rudeness. There are too many downvotes (without a comment on what could be done to improve the answer/question) and the vagueness of the answers (the answer deleted basically said that some things are OK in informal language, without saying anything specific about the case I was asking). When I wrote that I noticed people saying "there is [plural]" I don't need anyone to tell me that it is OK in informal English. I want to know what is grammatically right. I thought this was what this site was for, to learn the correct ways of saying things.

Comment: @RegDwighт And if the other reasons hadn't been enough to discourage me to come back, the answer that I didn't accept saying that "there's" is a contraction for both "there is" and "there are" would do the job.

Comment: @RegDwighт I am very active on the sister site [TeX.SE](tex.stackexchange.com/users/14). I recently complained there about the treatment of newbies, but my experience here made me realise things there are not bad at all. Have a look at the number of downvotes, questions being closed, tone of comments, and you will understand what I mean. I don't think I can change things here or contribute much. I don't know enough to answer questions, and why ask a question and be bashed with downvotes, vagueness and rude comments?

Comment: @Vivi: That's an apples and oranges comparison, I'm afraid. Here's why: the LaTeX site **will** downvote and close questions they deem unfit for the site, like [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20810) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2170). So, why does this happen so much more on ELU? That's simple: How many people on the planet are interested in boning up on their LaTeX skills? Versus how many people are wanting to improve their English? For that reason, if the number of questions being downvoted and closed on LaTeX was comparable, I would be shocked.

Comment: I get it. This forum is for people who know how to ask the question or for the people who already know the answer before asking it so that they would know how to ask the question "properly". All other askers, buzz off, you are not welcome. Go ask your silly question somewhere else.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: Surely you do **NOT** get it, if that's the message you are reading. No one is ever told to buzz off, and everyone is welcome. If questions aren't up to par, new users are given advice on how to improve them. Those who regard such comments as _helpful feedback_ usually catch on rather quickly, and become productive members of the community. Those who regard the feedback as a personal attack either run off and sulk like a toddler, or else complain on meta how everyone here is a "snob" because they'd prefer to see a newcomer strive for quality.

Comment: @Vivi sorry for the late reply, I only just got to the bottom of my inbox. You raise a whole number of points worth addressing for which the space here is not enough. It's unfortunate you didn't catch me in chat; I am there for most of the day, every day, but it appears I'm also on the exact opposite side of the globe from you. So I have created a [dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6849/room-for-regdwight-and-vivi) where I hope we can sort it all out even if our messages are 12 hours apart. Looking forward to it. Oh, and Merry Christmas.

Comment: I lurk this SE frequently. Many of the examples above were closed as duplicates. One with 17 similar? That's not snobbery just trying to keep questions unique as best as participants can.

Comment: @RegDwighт I think I took too long, sorry (travelling...). If you are still willing to discuss this, let me know. In the meantime, I think [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/42/42) is relevant to one of the issues I mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a high-rep user who votes to close a lot of questions, but not quite as many questions as some people, let me take a pass at the list:

I would have left the following questions open:

> 6) Do Shakespeare use the word “whence” incorrectly?

An interesting question that covers a question of legitimate interest to students of contemporary and historical English. I just nominated it for reopening.

> 16) Usage difference between modest vs decent?

There are some real subtleties here which may not be apparent from a dictionary. The main weakness of this question is that the OP hasn't done sufficient research, but that could be fixed with an edit.

Pretty much everything else is either duplicate or General Reference.

So do we have a problem? If there is a problem, it's the fact that it's easier to cast a close-vote than to edit a question, so marginal questions like the ones above get closed rather than edited. But the number of questions that fall between the gaps in this way is rather small, and doesn't account for the majority of close votes.

The reason that we close so many questions is because of the nature of our content. There are a lot of native English speakers, so we get a lot of [bike-shed questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality). And there are lots of English language learners, so we get a lot of questions which are too basic or demonstrate such a general misunderstanding of English that no real answer is possible. Neither of these things is the fault of the close-voters; they come with the territory.

Comment: the point you raise about the nature of our content is very pertinent, and I think it must be considered as we formulate our policy. however, i differ in that i don't think that learners are likely to ask mostly bike-shed questions. for me, the most fascinating parts about English language are those which are obvious to a native speaker, but cannot be perspicaciously explained to learners. making explicit the knowledge that we have is a great challenge for scholars of English, and it is often L2 learners who raise points which wouldn't have occurred to a native speaker.

Comment: I agree the Whence question is very interesting and perfectly on-topic. Thing is it was closed as "exact duplicate" - and it's really hard to argue with the fact a question with precisely the same gist has been asked and answered quite thoroughly. As normally I'm rabidly against closures, I must concede that one was okay.

Comment: @jlovegren, I meant to say that it's the *natives*, not the learners, who ask bike-shed questions. And I completely agree with you about good questions from learners, and we have a great many good questions of that sort. Just look at [Yoichi Oishi](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi).

Comment: As an epilogue of sorts, [#16](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94266) has since been both edited _and_ reopened.

Answer (score 8):

The ones that should have stayed open:

3): presumably there is a difference that could be uncovered with a little bit of research, and i would have liked to see what someone could find out.

6): again, this could have had some interesting well-researched answers. someone could show, for example, that compared to other contemporaneous writers, Shakespeare used the word in an apparently idiosyncratic way. (or show the opposite)

7): this is not necessary a duplicate since it asks specifically for usage in the case where the wh- word is serving as a relative pronoun. community members (hastily) assumed that all word-forms *who/whom* should have identical distribution.

9): i would have liked to see the answers on this one

10): that's one I edited in response to a challenge from the OP

12): a good answer could have discussed what it means for something to be a spelling vs. grammatical error.

13): the meanings of words are determined by usage (not formal logic), so a good answer could have examined actual usage of the word, and discussed whether it paralleled other similar-formed words.

14): a good answer would respond to the more general question on how *I got* and *I've got* differ.

15): could lead to an informative answer on anaphora binding. the commenter misleadingly suggested that anaphoric use of *did* usually binds a verb. instead it is a verb phrase.

16): this is a clearcut usage question which could be answered by examining usage data. another case where it was closed by those assuming it was a more trivial matter than it is.

17): a good answer would discuss whether there are similar-spelled words with a consistent pluralization pattern, or if *conch* is a *sui generis* case.

19): on variable placement of VP-modifying adverbs. i'd be surprised if a more general question has not been asked already, but it was not closed for reason of duplicate status.

The OP asks "Even if...do you really...", misleadingly suggesting that the only reasonable objection to question closures is that they are almost always in error. The real issue is that there is much less harm in leaving a poor question open than there is in closing a good question. Call the *error quotient* the proportion of closed questions which are good. Call the *false closure rate* the proportion of (in some objective sense) acceptable questions which are closed. Basically, the OP is claiming that we should only be concerned if the *error quotient* is on the order of 90%. This is fallacious reasoning: even if 90% of closed questions were bad questions, we should still be concerned for the good ones that do get closed.
What I am claiming is that the *false closure rate* is significantly above 0%, and that **is** a reason for concern. Some error will invariably occur, but I think the community needs to have a discussion about what would be an acceptable *false closure rate*, rather than bringing up the canard that there are many truly bad questions.

The obvious difference is that closed questions become invisible to common users after some time, and people who took some care and effort in responding to questions which are ultimately closed see their work get (effectively) deleted.

Comment: The question of whether to delete closed questions is a different matter altogether. That question probably should be asked, too.

Comment: “The OP is claiming that we should only be concerned if the error quotient is on the order of 90%.” No, I never claimed that. “The OP .. misleadingly suggests that the only reasonable objection to question closures is that they are almost always in error.” No, I just want to know if such closures represent proof that we are "cliquey snobby mates" as some claim. “The real issue is that there is much less harm in leaving a poor question open than there is in closing a good question.” I agree with that; that's a good question; perhaps you could ask that on meta, it deserves its own discussion.

Comment: @J.R. I ignored the *snobs* part of the question on purpose because  it's not the issue that I want to interact with; i don't want the tactless critics to be driving this debate. i hope you'll agree that the only important issue worth debating is whether the premature closing of questions is detrimental to the site. i do appreciate your suggestion to open a new question.

Comment: I don't agree that it's the _only_ issue worth debating or discussing; some strong words have been said, which is why I've asked _my_ question here. That said, if the ensuing discussion inspires you to inquire about another related issue – perhaps a more important and fundamental one – so much the better.

Comment: Read the answer to the duplicate question of (6). It answers (6) decisively (it says lots of Shakespeare's contemporaries said "from hence" and "from whence", although they didn't say "to whither" or "to thither"). It should have been closed. And (14) was closed because the OP had much too vague a question. It has now been revised, and has three votes for reopening.

Comment: @PeterShor fair enough; i am all in favor of closing duplicates if they have no substantial differences.

Comment: *The real issue is that there is much less harm in leaving a poor question open than there is in closing a good question.* --- I disagree with this statement, and I think this is the core problem.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ it's better if we can identify substantive differences in our values if progress is going to be made on this issue, so i'd invite you to contribute your perspective on my recent question in meta.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from [Verb or phrase meaning “to serve as evidence of one's character”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94307/verb-or-phrase-meaning-to-serve-as-evidence-of-ones-character), either I actually closevoted those questions myself, or at least I don't particularly disagree with those who did.

In total, I've *upvoted* questions and answers ten times more often than I've *closevoted*, and I almost never closevote questions (that admit of a meaningful answer at all) unless I can see that the OP's request has already been dealt with in an answer, a comment, or a link to a duplicate.

I certainly don't think ELU is "snobby". It seems to me almost everyone who asks a meaningful question ends up getting a meaningful answer. But once that answer has been provided, there's often little else left to say - in which case I say it's better to close the question.

---

On the one question where I don't agree the closevote, there are already 3 votes to *reopen*. It's worth pointing out it was closed as *not a real question* - and 24 hours after it was asked, the OP *still* hasn't responded to requests for more context. I think ELU is in fact *very* "open-minded".

Comment: "*But once that answer has been provided, there's often little else left to say - in which case I say it's better to close the question.*" This is where I disagree. It's rather arrogant for anyone other than the question asker to determine whether the question has been answered to completion. Just because *you* have little else to say, and you think you've provided a perfect and full answer, doesn't mean the original poster doesn't still have (maybe stupid) questions - or indeed that someone else confused about the same issue won't have questions 6 months later.

Comment: @Billy: I agree with everything you said, except the word "arrogant." (Had you said something more neutral, like "shortsighted," I'd utterly agree.) I see this as two side of a coin: a site can be overrun with questions of low quality, or a site can become too strict in enforcing an artificially rigid standard. Evidently, this community has people who are concerned both ways, which is fine with me. However, I'm tired of one camp assuming that the other is rooted in arrogant, xenophobic highbrow pseudo-intellectualism. Based on the help they regularly dispense, I believe that's inaccurate.

Comment: I don't know what "camp" you're on about, @J.R. I am a relatively new and neutral user here. I *do* find it arrogant, and I find SE as a whole (not just English) a little stuck in its ways. I don't care if english.SE is overrun with "questions of low quality" - indeed, these are the issues on which people most desperately need to be educated. Any culture of rejecting and/or dismissing such questions as not living up to any particular standard goes against everything I believe about education.

Comment: (I once had a history teacher who gave a passionate and inspiring speech in his first lesson about the importance of understanding over memorisation, of discussion over rote learning, and so on. Sadly, he didn't live up to his own standards. For the rest of the year, if someone tried to ask a question, he would sigh, deem it a distraction, patronise the student in question with comments on what a waste of his time it was, and point them at their textbook. He may have been correct - we were 11, so our questions probably *were* stupid - but he was an awful teacher. We learnt nothing.)

Comment: @Billy: I'm in education, and I largely come here because I like to help people (much like I did this morning; see my three comments on [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94507)). Also, I once explained my position on how I feel about "bad" questions on [this post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2694); feel free to disagree with my position, but I hope you don't conclude that your history teacher and I are of the same ilk.

Comment: @J.R. Has there been some misunderstanding? I'm not talking about *you*, and never have been. I'm talking about the closed questions in your first post. The closure of questions (stupid or not, profound or not) once they have been answered is far less rude than, but pedagogically equivalent to, my history teacher's method of teaching. A chapter reference, a snide comment, and the impression that he thought such questions were rather too trivial to bother with. (Sure, we got our *answers*, but we didn't just want *answers*. We were interested. We wanted *discussion*.)

Comment: @Billy: You can still *discuss* closed questions by posting comments, but bear in mind ELU is supposed to be a Q&A site/knowledge repository, not a chat site. If a question is closed prematurely (i.e. - it doesn't address some *precise* aspect of the issue that someone later seeks clarification on), they can always raise a new question. That mechanism will *in theory* eventually lead to better answers overall (any subsequent "clarifying answer" may well be merged into the original question, which is very likely to be reopened at that point).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, of course - but my main concern is that a large number of closed questions reflects badly on how welcoming the community is to new users - not just to the OP of a poorly written question, but also to people who are landed here by Google and read already closed questions with interest. Don't forget that SE doesn't even *let* new users comment. As easy as it is to love a community when you are well respected in it, this one looks abnormally insular from the outside.

Comment: @Billy “Large number of closed questions”? Just look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&pagesize=50&q=closed%3a1) for “large numbers of closed questions”. Those are large numbers: hundreds and hundreds per day. **AND STILL THEY COME!** Many are quite downvoted, too. Plus there are 50,000 more questions on the closevote queue waiting to be closed. That doesn’t even consider the deleted ones: [this shows](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today) that more than 50 posts have been deleted *in the last hour alone*. Really, ELU is soft and slow and cuddly.

Comment: @Billy: I wonder why you interpret large numbers of closed questions as "not welcoming to new users". Why don't you interpret them as "disrespectful of users in good standing"? If people started posting 20 questions a day about music, recipes, or porn, would you leave them open, just to be welcoming to new users? The purpose of this site is not to be welcoming to new users; the purpose of this site is to be welcoming to new users *with clear, on-topic questions*. And this is equally true of all sites of the network. Users that add value are welcome. Users that don't, aren't. Everywhere.

Comment: @tchrist If that is so, then so be it. I am forced to accept that the moderators do a good job of removing awful questions - but then I never denied that. I simply claimed that they also do a fine job of removing some valid questions. J.R. posted above a list of 20 more-or-less randomly selected questions that were closed; jlovegren contested the closure of 12 of them, Andrew Lazarus contested 7, JSB contested 2, and even Fumble was unsure about 1. Having too much work to do is a good explanation for its not getting done properly, but not an excuse, surely?

Comment: @RegDwighт I am not a user in good standing, so I don't purport to speak for them. As for the new users, well, I quote a few snippets from the FAQ: topics that are "welcomed here" include (a) "word choice and usage", (b) "grammar", (c) "pronunciation", (d) "spelling and punctuation". J.R.'s questions mostly fit happily into these categories (1a, 2c, 3a, 4d, 5a, 6ab, 7ab, 8d...). So why were these questions closed? Well, according to the FAQ, they were "not a good fit for this site", and the asker is encouraged to "improve" it. And yet, when I look at the actual reasons for closing given...

Comment: ...1, 5, 7 and 9 appear to have been deleted, 2 is now reopened, 3 is closed as "not a question" (one of the closevoters commented "too basic"?!), 4 is closed as exact duplicate (though the question has 4 upvotes and a once-upvoted comment from Kris claiming that it's not a duplicate at all), 6 is (correctly) closed as duplicate, 8 is closed as duplicate (the question indeed *is* a duplicate, but it's not answered in the thread it's redirected to - finally, the third link out of four answers the question, but frankly I disagree with the answer), and so on...

Comment: @Billy: that section defines what's on topic vs. what's off topic. *None* of the eight questions you mention have been closed as off-topic. Indeed, *four* of them have been closed as duplicates; that is, they are *expressly deemed on-topic*. One is too localized, two have been closed as "not clear" pending clarification, and the remaining one is actually reopened now. So I am not sure what your point is. That we should never close duplicates? That we should not ask for clarification from the OP? Something else? Do elaborate, I really do not understand.

Comment: ...my apologies for the long comment, but I hope this now answers your question. The mention of music, recipes and porn is a complete straw man - most of the questions I spent the time analysing above *were* clear and on-topic. There was one real duplicate, but there were two fake duplicates. One of them has now been re-opened. Four of them, duplicate or whatever, have been *removed* despite seeming perfectly legitimate to me from the title. And there is clear evidence of at least one closevoter deeming a certain question beneath themselves. Yes, this is unwelcoming - here and anywhere else.

Comment: @RegDwighт Pardon me, but that section defines what's *welcomed* and what's *not welcomed*. It states that very clearly in the section itself. You (plural) have *not welcomed* many questions that fall into this category. You are *unwelcoming*. This is the word you asked me to explain in your last post, isn't it?

Comment: @Billy: The mention of music, recipes and porn is not a straw man; it is a deliberately exaggerated argument to demonstrate a point that people otherwise like to ignore. (Namely that the supply of newbies who don't give a rat's tail about the site is unlimited; while the group of people willing to stick around and answer is tiny compared to that.) And in fact the argument is [not even that exaggerated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=497440#497440). People absolutely will, and do, post anything and everything. If you don't see that, that's a sign of things going right, not wrong.

Comment: @RegDwighт As in my response to tchrist, it's a sign of *some* things going right. And I am grateful to the moderators for every right thing that they do. But you said it yourself - bad questions need to be closed or removed, *and* good questions need to be kept. So it is a straw man in the context of *this* discussion, which is about a bunch of questions that all fall into the *welcomed* section of your FAQ.

Comment: @Billy: now you will have to pardon me, but you are splitting hairs. How is closing a question with a link to an answer *not* welcoming? How is asking OP for clarification not welcoming? You know what's unwelcoming in my book? Not reacting to a question at all, or just downvoting or closevoting without leaving a comment. What *is* your definition of "welcoming", that nothing should ever get closed? How many of said OPs said they felt unwelcomed? Why do you suppose they are? What is your evidence?

Comment: @RegDwighт I quote the FAQ again: "**Why are some questions closed?** Questions that *are not a good fit for this site* may be voted closed..." That italicised emphasis is my own - but those words are also a hyperlink, and when I click on it, the list of "welcomed" questions scrolls back down again and flashes at me. I'm not splitting hairs here - this has been *deliberately* written into the community guidelines by someone far more well respected than myself. The newest users who care about making a decent contribution will start posting on SE knowing nothing but *what's written in the FAQ*.

Comment: And, how many OPs felt unwelcomed? I did myself once, a few years back, when I first came to SE under a different account name, *read the FAQ first*, then posted a question, and had it immediately trashed and closed by 'experienced community members'. You'll be pleased to hear that it wasn't ELU, but the treatment I received was the same as the treatment those 20 questions above have received.

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/not-a-real-question-really Or how about this user? (This took me about 5 seconds to find, and I wasn't even looking for it! Okay, she's not the OP, but...)

Comment: @Billy: Martha is a staunch defender of the "Come one, come all" approach - but for all the hoohah about that particular closure, it's worth noting that the only original answer doesn't actually address the specific question *Is corrosion an onomatopoeia?* I'd also point out that Martha's edit added 3-4 times as much text as in the original question, in order to make it reopenable. But the OP never helped (or even reacted *at all*) to attempts to salvage the question. I think collectively ELU bent over backwards to accommodate a poorly-posed question from a "drive-by" supplicant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree - but Mark *does* make the good point that "onomatopoeia" does not have the same narrow connotation in all languages as it does in English. This combination of no good answer and confirmation that the question is sensible sounds like a good reason *not* to close it, to me. Martha's edits don't change the question at all, they simply explain the seemingly non-standard usage of "onomatopoeia". And to "the OP never reacted at all": the question was asked, *and* closed, *and* reopened, yesterday. They might not even have checked ELU in that time. Give them a chance!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mind if that was the goal: answer, then close as not likely to be useful in the future. But there was that meta, I can't locate it at the moment, that was practically a call to arms against this class of questions, with a strong demand to stop users from answering them. And it wasn't like anyone would seem to disagree with the notion - the idea being "if we don't prevent answers it will encourage more of these questions".

Which means the current state is not a positive, target, desired state of things, but just a result of weakness of the moderation system unable to react fast enough to prevent users from answering.

Answer (score 2):

At a first-look minimum, I see merit in 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, and 16. As a practical matter, I don't see a compelling reason to delete any but the obvious duplicates. It's not like we get charged by the byte for open questions.

I can't ***imagine*** a legitimate reason to close 16 on a forum that purports to be about English usage. The difference between the relevant definitions of "modest" and "decent" in a dictionary will not enlighten someone who doesn't already know about the subtle differences between them. (The answer given before closure is, by the way, excellent in this regard.) As I alleged before, the size of the space between "General Reference" and "Too Localised" depends wholly on how the egos of the Guardians are feeling that day.

Moreover, I don't think the replies to 5 and 13 are even that good!

On 5, Use of "Doctor" for "Ph.D." has a number of implications and subtleties. Many medical doctors do not like it and it would be wise to use "Professor" (if true) or "Ph.D." instead in a social situation where an M.D. might be offended. On the other hand, there are institutions where the use of "Dr. X" instead of "Professor X" is customary. The comment about surgeons being called "Mister" is British usage only without being so labeled (there is at least one murder mystery that hinges on this); in the USA they are always "Doctor". At the least, it would have been useful to solicit from the OP some idea of the context in which he needed to know this.

On 13, the answers aren't blunt enough about mentioning that nonX, when an infrequent construction like nonlesson, carries a significant snark payload. The question is a good one and the downvotes are nonhelpful.

Comment: You and I have butt heads over the past week, but I'll admit, I admire the analysis you put into your answer here. (I still wish you'd refrain from snarky accusations like "My guess is that we have a lot of grad students and abandoned Ph.D.s who feel better about their superior knowledge of English after slagging (and closing) foreigners' silly, or not so silly, questions," which strikes me as rather incendiary, unproductive and inaccurate.) I appreciate what you wrote here; I found it informative and (almost) on-the-mark (I really don't think Gen Ref & Too Localized is ego-based).

Comment: @J.R. I may have gone overboard and I'm sorry if I offended you. It's too easy to do that on the Internet from any perspective, whether those who vote to close or those who think the number of such votes has gone too high.

Answer (score 2):

### I just want to say this

There are a few users on this site that make this site seem very derogatory. And [it is stuff like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/is-attempt-a-durative-or-a-punctual-verb) that make people say that those who are closing questions are snobs... because they are. (I don't care if the question deserved to be closed--like in the example I used, but if you're going to close a question, remember that there are supposed to be manners and that you're not supposed to be rude. And people who have called me out on my bad tone, are usually the same people who are rude to begin with. *Not all, but the small majority*)

Now, with the example I just gave, yes, that question is questionable. However, that is no excuse for those users to be badgering the user the way they did.

When I first started coming onto this site, I enjoyed it. But then I saw so many high rep users badgering lower rep users in a similar fashion to this and I can't stand this site anymore.

I understand that most questions that get closed are truly closed for a reason (like that question probably will be), however, I am posting this in response to your saying:

> However, when I search for evidence of that snobbery, I keep finding a
>   slew of rather mediocre questions – usually with helpful answers, by
>   the way – rather than hard evidence of an unhelpful clique. But maybe
>   I'm just missing something, in which case maybe you can help me out.

Again, I know the question isn't good. But why should it suddenly be okay to do what they did?

Comment: I sympathize with your feeling there's some 'snobbery' around here; but the example you offer exhibits none that I see. There are no downvotes, no closevotes; the first comment asks for some clarification, which was forthcoming and was very helpful in providing context for three answers. One of those answers makes a lighthearted joke which is directly relevant to the question, and which the questioner takes in that spirit. What rudeness or badgering do you see?

Comment: I agree with what @StoneyB said, and that comment addresses the heart of my question. Some folks are SO convinced that ELU folks are snobs, that _any_ request for clarification, _any_ exhortation to do some additional research, _any_ votes to close irrespective of quality all counts as mounting evidence that we are a rude, insular, snobby, community. This O.P. asked, **"I'd appreciate your thoughts on this,"** and, when a regular did just that – takes time to find a pertinent link, and ask a straightforward question – that's considered "badgering."

Comment: Moreover, in this case, you seem to disregard how _helpful_ the comment by @FumbleFingers actually is. I didn't know what a _durative_ vs. _punctual_ verb was; at least w/ FF's comment, I could find that out and learn something. The O.P. could have included some information like that, and probably _should_ have included some information like that, but FF took up the slack. More importantly, if any rude behavior is exhibited in that conversation, I'd say the OP's reply seems much ruder than FF's comment. Read it again with a more open mind, and try giving FF the benefit of the doubt this time.

Comment: @StoneyB and J.R. : I'm not talking about the comment FumbleFingers left. I'm talking about the first answer that was left. Answers are supposed to help people, not jab. And if we want to talk about reading, I already know the question was off. I even said that. I didn't manage to get a screenshot of the comment MetaEd left (has since been deleted), but did it occur to anyone OP was frustrated because of how *unhelpful* the first answer was?

Comment: I don't know how anyone can stick up for a smart alec response that should have been a comment, not an answer. And yes, it is a jab, because it implies that the question has no merit. I'm not saying all ELU people are snobs, I just think that ***some*** ELU people have a little too much air in their heads from an ego trip. My only regret in this is that I didn't get that screenshot because it was the perfect example of snobbery on this site.

Comment: @Souta  That was not a jab, it was an *example* of durative use of *attempt* which spoke directly to OP's question; jocularly expressed, perhaps, but OP's response seems to me to understand that. This is not to say that rudeness never occurs; but in this instance I don't think it did.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, OP understood: `the perfective only relates to a finished action with a punctual verb. thats why i think it is punctual. can anyone elaborate an answer that contradicts that without trying to be funny or clever..` And if it were just an example, why not state so and then elaborate? Aren't answers supposed to have something backing up their statements?

Comment: `i d like to hear the explanation if anyone knows it. thanks` But as you say, OP understood the first answer.

Comment: And I'd like to say, I know I'm coming off as rude right now, but I'm frustrated myself. It is one thing to have a sense of humor, but it is another when you use that as a smokescreen as I feel has been done in this case.

Comment: I don't think you're being rude, I just think you've picked a poor, or at best marginal example. Note that MετάEd's response came right on the heels of the original post - half an hour before OP provided additional information about use with the perfective which completely shifted the focus and depth of the question and demanded a more elaborate answer. MετάEd's never shy about asking for improvements to questions he regards as weak; in this case he responded chattily, concisely, and with welcoming humour to a chatty, concise question.

Comment: One more thing - it's not entirely irrelevant that just mentioning the punctual/durative contrast created the presumption that OP was among the most sophisticated visitors to this site - it's not something novices know about.

Comment: @Souta: Wow, if _that_ constitutes badgering, then number me among the rudest users on the site. In fact, my profile even makes explicit mention of the fact that I _enjoy_ embedding self-references into comments and answers, much like I did in my answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82793). (I've never _meant_ to "jab"; I've figured such answers serve a dual purpose: they provide an extra example of usage, and are somewhat entertaining, too.) Maybe I made a bad assumption about what you were referring to, but my reply remains the same, just change "FF" to "ME".

Comment: @J.R. You're taking my point wrong, but I'm running out of argument here. Again, I wish I had a screenshot of what was *originally* there. As for you comparing yourself to someone who smokescreen-jokes, you make your post funny with polite-humor *and* explain what it means. But whatever, I've ran out of argument and I chose a poor example for ELU bullying in the first place.

Comment: @Souta: Sorry if I took your point wrong, but you're the one who called me a snob. (Read the last three words of the second sentence of your answer.) (BTW, I realize that you probably didn't mean to direct that label at me personally, but you did answer my question by calling us snobs collectively, even if you did add a disclaimer later in your paragraph. And I still think the O.P.'s reply to FF is perhaps the rudest thing in that question.)

Comment: I did not know I was being talked about. Sorry to respond late. My points: (*i*) I have no idea what I might have said in a deleted comment. If I was rude, I regret it. (*ii*) J.R. rightly takes my post and followup comment as answers by humorous example, with no hidden criticism intended. Indeed, (*iii*) when a question is problematic, we should be polite and direct about it and suggest practical solutions. (*iv*) Correcting someone can result in loss of face. But we will get nowhere unless we assume the person is mature enough to bear corrections.

Comment: @MετάEd The deleted comment was a bit biting towards the OP of the question I brought up. However, I will have to admit, after cooling down and taking a third-party observation, I did overreact here. But I still stand by that I chose the wrong question to point out my point. As for you responding late, no need for apologies. You weren't exactly notified that an oversensitive ELU user was ripping your "motives" apart.